# How to style dynamically created objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner at jQuery so I would like to use it as less as possible. I want to change the padding of a dynamically created button in JavaScript, how do I do this?

```js
function addButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = "New Button!"
  document.body.append(btn)
  
  btn.style.padding = "7px"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addButton()">Add Button</button>
```

Comment: What is the issue here? The "New Button" seems to already have a padding of 7px.

Comment: I want each button to have a padding of 7px.

Comment: Yes, each newly created button is having padding. Is it not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track; i.e

1) `createElement`,

2) `append` or `appendChild`, and

3) add any event listeners using `addEventListener` or classes using `classList`.

Don't directly set `el.style.` properties, just like you don't directly set style in HTML `<el style="...">`.

Also, use `'` instead of `"` in JS, and `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` HTML attribute.

```js
function addButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'New Button!';
  document.body.append(btn)

  btn.classList.add('red');
  btn.classList.add('padded');
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addButton);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.padded {
  padding: 7px;
}
```

```html
<button>Add Button</button>
```